# Java HQL tree display

Tags: java, hibernate, tree, hql

I have a class named Rule, which contains a Set of childRules(each of the components of the Set are other classes). I am doing a HQL query which is marked as lazy="false".

The problem I am facing is that the HQL brings out classes that match my search pattern on the top level, but those classes can have as a childRules which do not match the pattern.

My question is about how can I get to display only those rules that match my pattern(they can be childRules).

Thx

My class looks like this :

```
public class Rule
{

private Set<Rule> childRules = null;
private String name = null;
private Long id = null;
private Long parentId = null;

//with the respective setters/getter
}
```

Comment: can you please post some code?

Answer (score 0):

You could do re-search starting from the node you found to search for any rule that doesn't match your search pattern.